# No Duplicates in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, rows, multiple-columns, cells

I'm working in C# displaying some data in a DataGridView and I'd like it to not allow you to add a duplicate key.. Right now, my DataGridview is pretty simple with just 2 columns. One is called "Key" the other is called "Value". What i want, is for when the user edits or adds a new entry to the DataGridView, it checks if there is already a duplicate and cancels the edit/creation of the new row. Here is my current code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells[0].Value.Equals(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value))
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]);
            break;
        }
    }

    refresh();
}
```

It isn't working at all... Can someone tell me how I should be doing this?.. Thanks!

Edit: I'm also getting this error on the dataGridView1.Rows.Remove() call -

```
Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the  SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.
```

Edit:

The DataGridView looks like this

```
Key     | Value 
----------------
blah    | something 
somekey | somevalue
```

Comment: What I did when avoiding duplicates was this: I let the user enters whatever she wants. Then, when the Datagrid loses focus or the validation button is clicked, I erase the duplicated rows. I made a little routine to delete duplicated rows, but it checks the values in all the cells in the row: http://programacionamartillazos.blogspot.com/2012/03/c-rutina-para-eliminar-filas-repetidas.html

Answer (score 1):

It is probably your `foreach` loop, which doesn't allow deleting rows.

Try something like this:

```
private void dgv_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  for (int i = 0; i < DataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++) {
    DataGridViewRow row = DataGridView1.Rows[i];
    if (row.Cells[0].Value == DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value) {
      DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
      DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = i;
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

I do not allow row editing, though, so I could be wrong.

**EDIT:** Just a quick edit. I'd set the `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` to `e.RowIndex`, but that row would have just been deleted!

Comment: Still getting the same problems :/. It removes any row that i edit, No matter if there's a duplicate. and some times i get that error i put in the latest edit..

Comment: Rats. I just noticed also that I had set `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = e.RowIndex` after that row had just been deleted, so I updated the code. I don't think that would change your end result, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only guessing but I've tried your code and I've seen a logical error:
if you debug it you'll see that with the foreach loop you'll necessary hit the element you just edited, which is obviously equal to itself.

I suggest you to change the loop to a for or to check if the row index is the same.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code for that,

```
protected void GV_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
     DataTable dt1 = ViewState["dt"] as DataTable;
     if (e.CommandName == "Add")
     {
DataRow dr;
          dr = dt1.NewRow();
dr["DED_Id"] = Material_Id;
          dr["DED_Name"] = Material;
          dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
          dt1.AcceptChanges();
          ViewState["dt"] = dt1;
     }
}
```